# Why does my regression model return an intercept even though I set fit_intercept= False?

Tags: python, statistics, regression, statsmodels

Basically, I am trying to run a regression based on a dataframe without an intercept, so I set fit intercept to false, yet the following code yields a parameters that include an intercept. Anyone have an idea why this may be the case?

```
model2 = smf.ols('Y ~ X', data=df_final)
result2 = model2.fit(cov_type = 'HAC', cov_kwds = {'maxlags':5}, fit_intercept= False)
result2.params

Intercept    0.032649
X            0.014521
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Please post a small, complete minimal example with import statements and a few data points - that way I could run the exact same code as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running an OLS model using a formula an intercept is added by default. One way to omit the intercept term is to add a `-1` to the formula:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=20),
                   'Y': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=20)})

model = smf.ols('Y ~ X - 1', data=df)
result = model.fit()
```

The fitted model now only contains a single parameter (for `X`):

```
X    0.691876
dtype: float64
```

If you're not using the formula api, then the OLS model doesn't include an intercept so you don't need to worry about it (in that case you need to explicitly add it to your data)

I'm not sure where you got the `fit_intercept` parameter from as I cant find any reference to it in the statsmodels [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.from_formula.html) or [source code](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels). Maybe you're thinking of linear regression using [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression), which does use a parameter to control the intercept